# Access to a callback's method from Mustache

Tags: php, oop, callback, mustache, template-engine

Can anyone please explain how to create objects and call to it's methods from a Mustache template?

---

I want to add a few callbacks to Mustache as helper:

```
$options['helpers'] = array(
    'Post' => array('\Classes\Post', 'getObject')
);
```

Here is a sample class:

```
namespace Classes;

class Post
{
    public static function getObject()
    {
        return new Post(\Request::postId());
    }

    public function post()
    {
        $post = new \stdClass;
        $post->title = 'Title';
        $post->content = 'Content';

        return $post;
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        $comment = new \ArrayObject();

        $comment[0] = new stdClass;
        $comment[0]->name = 'David';
        $comment[0]->content = 'I\'m David';

        $comment[1] = new stdClass;
        $comment[1]->name = 'Mary';
        $comment[1]->content = 'I\'m Mary';

        $comment[2] = new stdClass;
        $comment[2]->name = 'Sana';
        $comment[2]->content = 'I\'m Sana';

        return $post;
    }
}
```

And use it in post.Mustache file:

```
<h1>{{Post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{Post.content}}</p>
<hr>
{{#Post.comments}}
    <b>{{name}}</b> Said: {{content}}<br><br>
{{/Post.comments}}
```

But, It seems that this is not the right way to access chained methods and properties?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Mustache works a lot better if you pass in values rather than having the template call out to get them :)

```
$m->render($tpl, ['Post' => Post::getObject()]);
```

In case you're interested in the longer answer:

Helpers are just bonus values in your rendering context. So adding your Post helper is equivalent to calling render() with `['Post' => ['Post', 'getObject']]`.

In Mustache, if the *value* of a tag is a function, it's treated in a special way (they're called lambdas). You can see examples [on the Mustache.php wiki](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#lambdas).

So in your case, you're running into weirdness with this distinction. Basically, the value of `{{Post}}` inside your render call isn't a new post, it's the callable `['Post', 'getObject']`. So that value is triggering the lambda logic rather than normal string interpolation.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the above answer, and your great Mustache implementation. Because of our special architecture, principles and limits, we can't add objects or lambdas to Mustache, array callbacks are our only option. So, we are going to make a decision to either fork Mustache or implement our own template engine that fits our needs. Thanks again for your great Mustache implementation ;{